# Is it possible to apply .length to Titlepane

Tags: javascript, dojo

I was wondering whether if it is possible to apply .length to the Titlepane. For example, if I had a list of names in an object array & I wished to have a title pane created for each name:

```
     var html = '';
         for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
         html += data[i].Name+'<br>';
         targetNode.innerHTML = html;
```

At the moment that loop will just display all the names that I have in a list. Therefore, is it possible to have a titlepane created for each name & the names to be placed inside as content?

If anyone has any examples or advice on how I would go about this, that would be great.

EDIT :

```
    var xhrArgs = {
url: "http://131.41.28.41:3000/pages.json",
handleAs: 'json',
timeout : 2000,

load: function(data){

 for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
var titlePane = new TitlePane({
  title: 'Title Pane ' + i,
  content: '<div>' + data[i].Name + '</div>'
});
titlePane.placeAt(dom.byId('ok'));
}
  },
error: function(error){
  targetNode.innerHTML = "An unexpected error occurred: " + error;
  }
 };

 // Call the asynchronous xhrGet
 var deferred = dojo.xhr.get(xhrArgs);
 });

 });
```

Comment: What do you mean by titlepane?

Comment: @MarcellFülöp it's a dojo widget http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dijit/TitlePane.html

Comment: Ah OK... I don't Dojo :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is indeed possible to create a new title pane for each object in an array:

```
require(['dijit/TitlePane'],function(TitlePane){
  for(var i=0; i<data.length;i++){
    var titlePane = new TitlePane({
      title: 'Title Pane '+i,
      content:'<div>'+data[i].Name+'</div>'
    });
    titlePane.placeAt(/* dom node where all titlepanes should be placed */);
  }
});
```

For more information on the dijit TitlePane, look at the [reference guide](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dijit/TitlePane.html).

A working jsfiddle of the concept can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9SqgE/).

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. Although I get an error that "undefined is not an object" Is this correct?- titlePane.placeAt(dom.byId("ok")

Comment: I was missing a closing parenthesis.  Also added a working jsfiddle example.

Comment: thanks, but it still is getting the same error, do have any ideas why that may be. I've put a snippet in my original question

Comment: Is the [DOM ready](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14289334/im-having-trouble-placing-a-dojo-widget-in-the-page/14301558#14301558) already? Did you require `dojo/dom` module?